# How to get ipv4 address exactly of another device connected same Wifi network that the client ID was known

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, networking

How do I get ipv4 of another device connected same wifi network?
I used below code (C# - Unity):

```
string ipv4 = "";
string hostName = "anp.local";
var host = Dns.GetHostEntry(hostName);
foreach (var ip in host.AddressList)
{
    Debug.Log("IP: " + ip.ToString());
    if (ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
    {
        ipv4 = ip.ToString();
    }
}
```

I got a wrong result: 125.235.4.59 on Window and Android.
Expect result should be 192.168.1.100 (work on Ipad)
My goal is able to connect another device in same wifi network on Window/Android/IOS platforms and I planed using ipv4 for it.

Comment: Are you sure this is even possible? I ask beacuse on most networks device communication between deviceso on the wifi network is severely limited. THis is to avoid broadcast traffic that would easily overload it. Plus WIFI often is behind NAT to avoid - people setting up servers etc. I am not sure this is a programming question - it may be better suited for serverfault (as in: how the heck is the particular wifi set up), but that reuires you do provide a lot more info.

Comment: my case is connecting between an application (in/ios/android) to Theta device(a camera device) via wifi. With connecting via ipv4, if I input ipv4 manually it will work as I expect. Not set up anything on wifi, there only is a device (installed the application) and a theta. so with that solution i whether i can get right ip (like 192.168.... above).

Comment: Oh, one of thos crappy networks. Have that on Sony cameras too - somoene thought it is a smart idea that "wifi support" means "the camera acts as wifi hotsport".ö

Comment: Theta camera can work same "the camera acts as wifi hotsport" with mobile devices =)))

Comment: I have deleted the tag [tag:UnityScript] from your question as this question is about C# and not UnityScript. Please note that UnityScript is its own (deprecated) scripting language and not a blanket tag for any kind of script in Unity (as explained in the tag information)